# ClickHouse JSON parse exception: Cannot parse input: expected ',' before

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I'm trying to add JSON data to ClickHouse from Kafka. Here's simplified JSON:

```json
{
  ...
   "sendAddress":{
      "sendCommChannelTypeId":4,
      "sendCommChannelTypeCode":"SMS",
      "sendAddress":"789345345945"},
   ...
}
```

Here's the steps for creating table in ClickHouse, create another table using Kafka Engine and creating MATERIALIZED VIEW to connect these two tables, and also connect CH with Kafka.

Creating the first table

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab 
(
    ...

    sendAddress Tuple (sendCommChannelTypeId Int32, sendCommChannelTypeCode String, sendAddress String),
     ...

)Engine = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY applicationId
ORDER BY (applicationId);
```

Creating a second table with Kafka Engine SETTINGS:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab_kfk
(
    ...
    sendAddress Tuple (sendCommChannelTypeId Int32, sendCommChannelTypeCode String, sendAddress String),
    ...
)ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'localhost:9092',
       kafka_topic_list = 'topk2',
       kafka_group_name = 'group1',
       kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow',
       kafka_row_delimiter = '\n';
```

Create MATERIALIZED VIEW

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tab_mv TO tab AS
SELECT ... sendAddress, ...
FROM tab_kfk;
```

Then I try to SELECT all or specific items from the first table - tab and get nothing. Logs is following [image: exception]

OK. Just add '[]' before curly braces in the sendAddress like this:

```json
"authkey":"some_value",
   "sendAddress":[{
      "sendCommChannelTypeId":4,
      "sendCommChannelTypeCode":"SMS",
      "sendAddress":"789345345945"
   }]
```

And I still get a mistake, but slightly different:
[image]
What should I do to fix this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 ways to fix it:

1. Not use nested objects and flatten messages before inserting to Kafka topic. For example such way:

```json
{
    ..
    "authkey":"key",
    "sendAddress_CommChannelTypeId":4,
    "sendAddress_CommChannelTypeCode":"SMS",
    "sendAddress":"789345345945",
    ..
}
```

2. Use [Nested data structure](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested/) that required to change the JSON-message schema and table schema:

```json
{
    ..
    "authkey":"key",
    "sendAddress.sendCommChannelTypeId":[4],
    "sendAddress.sendCommChannelTypeCode":["SMS"],
    "sendAddress.sendAddress":["789345345945"],
    ..
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab_kfk
(
    applicationId Int32,
    ..
    sendAddress Nested(
        sendCommChannelTypeId Int32,
        sendCommChannelTypeCode String,
        sendAddress String),
    ..
)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'localhost:9092',
       kafka_topic_list = 'topk2',
       kafka_group_name = 'group1',
       kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow',
       kafka_row_delimiter = '\n',
       input_format_import_nested_json = 1 /* <--- */
```

Take into account the setting [input_format_import_nested_json](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-input_format_import_nested_json).

3. Interpret input JSON-message as string & parse it manually (see [github issue #16969](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/16969#issuecomment-726754451)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab_kfk
(
    message String
)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS 
    ..
    kafka_format = 'JSONAsString', /* <--- */
    ..

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW tab_mv TO tab 
AS
SELECT 
    ..
    JSONExtractString(message, 'authkey') AS authkey,
    JSONExtract(message, 'sendAddress', 'Tuple(Int32,String,String)') AS sendAddress,
    ..
FROM tab_kfk;
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading at [this commit](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/commit/ebbd47012e85a4796beb8c06d48717b0e16150bd#), I believe for release 23.1, that a new setting `input_format_json_read_objects_as_strings` will allow converting nested json to String.

Example:

```sql
SET input_format_json_read_objects_as_strings = 1;
CREATE TABLE test (id UInt64, obj String, date Date) ENGINE=Memory();
INSERT INTO test FORMAT JSONEachRow {"id" : 1, "obj" : {"a" : 1, "b" : "Hello"}, "date" : "2020-01-01"};
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

| id | obj | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a" : 1, "b" : "Hello"} | 2020-01-01 |

[docs](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#input_format_json_read_objects_as_strings)

Of course, you can still use the materialized view to convert the String object to the correct column types using the same technics as for parsing `JSONAsString` format